# Preference for static keyword in Java

Tags: java

Recently I was checking a code online and found the output of the following code :

```
public class Sequence { 

    Sequence() { 
        System.out.print("c "); 
    }

    { 
        System.out.print("y "); 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        new Sequence().go(); 
    }
    void go() { 
        System.out.print("g "); 
    }

    static{
        System.out.print("x "); 
    }

}
```

as:

```
x y c g
```

Can anyone please help me to know about the functionality of this code.

Comment: Next time please indent your code properly. Then you will get more answers and less downvotes.

Comment: Debug it and you'll know, better than any explanation.

Comment: thanks Uwe and Maroun

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can anyone please help me to know about the functionality of this code.

Sure. The very first thing that happens is that the class is initialized as per [section 12.4.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2). This involves running the static initializers of the class, as per [section 8.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7). Here we have a static initializer which prints `x`.

The `main` method then creates an instance of `Sequence`. This follows [section 12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5) of the JLS. First the superclass constructor (`Object` here) is called, then the instance initializers ([section 8.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.6)) then the constructor body. Here you have an instance initializer which prints `y`, and a constructor body which prints `c`.

Finally, the `go` method is executed which prints `g`.

Answer (score 1):

It is an exam quiz question to make sure you can figure out in which order the various constructors and init-blocks are executed.

1. static initializers
2. instance initializers
3. constructors

You can make this more complex by having super-classes.

Or by having more than one of those initializer blocks.

Comment: Indeed Static blocks are not being moved into the constructor, but initialization blocks does.

Answer (score 0):

`static block` ,`instance block` `constructor` and then finally any methods which was called explicitly

Answer (score 0):

This looks suspeciously as an exam question. To understand the answer, you can break down the parts of your code into:

1. Constructor (which prints out "c ")

   ```
   Sequence() { 
       System.out.print("c "); 
   }
   ```
2. Instance initializer (which prints out "y ")

   ```
   { 
       System.out.print("y "); 
   }
   ```
3. main method (which creates an instance of Sequence and calls go on this instance)

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       new Sequence().go();
   }
   ```
4. The go method (which prints out "g ")

   ```
   void go() {
       System.out.print("g ");
   }
   ```
5. Static initializer (which prints out "x ")

   ```
   static {
       System.out.print("x ");
   }
   ```

In Java the order of execution is: (3) main method, (5) static initializer, (2) instance initializer, (1) constructor, go method (4).

To learn more about initializing you can read the tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Comment: Thanks Soren Its best way to check the flow if debug is not available